# Copy text from PDF with custom FONT

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe

I am trying to copy some text from a PDF. But When I paste it in a word file, it is just some garbage. Something like മുഖവുര. The PDF is in Malayalam language. When I see File->Properties->Fonts, It says BRHMalayalam (Embedded Subset) as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

I installed various Malayalam fonts but still no luck. Can anyone please guide me?

The PDF I am trying to copy from is https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3QCwY9Vanoza0tBdFJjd295WEE&authuser=0

Comment: Having an example document is the only absolutely certain way to diagnose exactly what is going on here...

Comment: David, here's the PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3QCwY9Vanoza0tBdFJjd295WEE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Installing fonts won't help, since they are embedded in the document. The reader will use the ones in the document.

In fact it almost certainly **must** use the ones on the document, because it will probably have used character codes specific to each font subset.

Your PDF probably has character codes which are not Unicode values, and does not contain ToUnicode CMaps for the fonts in question (note the same font name embedded multiple times). There is no realistic way to copy the text.

The best you can do is OCR it.

Comment: Watch out with the statement: "The reader will use the ones in the document." Some viewers (such as Adobe Acrobat and Adobe Reader) have a preference that configures them to use local fonts instead of the fonts embedded in the document for performance reasons. It's a hateful option for anyone involved with quality PDF documents and by default it's set to use local fonts...

Comment: And almost certainly will give incorrect answers with a re-encoded subset font, which is almost certainly what we have here.I'd consider that option to be equivalent to 'broken' personally. Also I can't find that option in my various versions of Acrobat or Reader. Of course, there are so many options.....

Comment: Not sure when they started with that, but I've known it for many years. In the preferences, there should be a tab (well, they use a list now because they have too many options) called "Page display" (though I believe it was once just called "display") and that normally should have the option. Together with the overprint preview disaster option.

Comment: Well, there is a 'local fonts' option there, but t doesn't use local fonts instead of embedded ones for me. As far as I can see that affects the behaviour of Acrobat when fonts aren't embedded in the PDF file. As far as I can see, if the font is not embedded, Acrobat won't use the locally installed OS fonts, and only uses its own fonts (if this option is set). Whcih allows you a better idea of how the PDF will look on another computer if you don't embed fonts. Of course, not embedding fonts is a Bad Thing......

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the file, and confirming the answer already given by @KenS, the problem with this PDF document is in fact how it's constructed. Or rather how the font in the document has been embedded.

The document contains a number of Times and Arial fonts, for which the text can be copied successfully. Those fonts are embedded as a subset with a `WinAnsi` encoding. What is actually in the file is close enough to that, that the text seems to copy out well.

The problem font (BRHMalayalam) is also embedded as a subset, and its encoding is *also* set as `WinAnsiEncoding`, which completely doesn't make sense.

[image]

And because the font doesn't contain a `ToUnicode` mapping table, a PDF viewer has no other choice when copying and pasting to assume the characters in the PDF are indeed Win Ansi encoding which means you end up with (garbled) latin characters.

Comment: So, does it mean the PDF is useless to me?

Comment: As far as copy and paste is concerned, pretty much, yes. Your only option would be to convert it to images and OCR it. The OCR engine - if it supports the correct language - should be able to get a good amount of the actual text for you. But the PDF file as it is doesn't contain enough information to extract the text correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the pdf file to word file and then edit or copy or modify the text present in the file simple :)
and after completion go to file -> save as -> and change the format of doc to pdf ..hope u understood :)